# Redirecting an ip in Java

Tags: java, redirect, proxy, ip

For the past few weeks, I have been scouring the internet, the minds of computer programmers, and just a few random people over the situation I am looking to overcome. Basically, what I am trying to do it write a AntiJoinBot "plugin" (if you will) for the popular game Minecraft. This would be like all others in respect that it blocks IPs based on if they are using a proxy or not, but this AntiJoinBot is running on a different VPS than the actual server.

This is the best graph I can make of the situation (it's not that good):

> (non-minecraft server) Connection -> Proxy check -> Redirect to the
>   server -> Minecraft

The only problem is, I need to be able to redirect the IP and close the connection so that the player's real IP is the one that would connect to the server. If the connection is not able to be closed, it would cause real problems due to some of the plugins we are running.

If you have a solution or a better way to do this, please help me.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't just put both elements on the same server and intercept all server traffic with a proxy check?

Comment: Yes, the join bot still will use the server's resources. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: If the minecraft server interface is pure HTTP you could possibly get away with an HTTP redirect provided the client is using standard HTTP libraries it might support it.  If the client/server are not using HTTP but some custom binary protocol (seems likely) then you can't do a redirect without a mod to the client.  You can do a full proxy though.  If you do find a way to do a redirect how will you stop malicious clients from simply storing the redirected IP and bypassing your server entirely?

Comment: I believe it runs through SOCKS connections, not HTTP (haven't looked much into the server side code). The reason I do believe this will be effective is the people creating the problems are more of "skids" than anything else. They will not know how to bypass it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand, why does this question relate to `minecraft` tag. As I see, you really need simple ip redirector.

Comment: Because, Andremonity, the redirector has to be compatible with the minecraft client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection of connections along the lines that you want requires support from the (application) protocol.  TCP/IP does not support it.  AFAIK, SOCKS does not support it either.  Unless the Minecraft application protocol (and by implication, Minecraft clients and servers) include support for redirection, you are out of luck.

(FWIW - that's how HTTP redirection works.  HTTP has a "protocol element" that allows the server to tell the client to redirect, and where to redirect to.  The client then resends the original request to a new address.)

But that doesn't mean that you can't deal with the pests.  It just means that the redirection approach is not viable.  Try a custom proxy or an IP filter / redirector instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the server's resources on the cost of increase Traffic.
I am not sure with the answer but may be by looking into the concept of LBS(Load Balancing Server) you may find the answer.
 LBS is purely defined and controlled by us so you can manage the resources of two servers using one load balancing server.